# hidden select-option change detection by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select, onchange

I am trying to detetect the select list change if the select list is hidden and setted by js.

My code is here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pj2t6jw/)

```
<select onchange="myfunction()" style="display:none">
  <option value="0">zero</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
<button class=z>zero</button>
<button class=o>one</button>
<button class=t>two</button>
```

```
$('select').change(function() {
  alert("ok");
});
$('.z').click(function() {
  $("select").val('0');
});
$('.o').click(function() {
  $("select").val('1');
});
$('.t').click(function() {
  $("select").val('2');
});
```

I need a solution to call the change function by the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `change` event raised when you set the value of a `select` element programmatically. To work around this you can `trigger()` one manually:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  console.log('changed', this.value)
});
$('.z').click(function() {
  $("select").val('0').trigger('change');
});
$('.o').click(function() {
  $("select").val('1').trigger('change');
});
$('.t').click(function() {
  $("select").val('2').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="display: none">
  <option value="0">zero</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
<button class="z">zero</button>
<button class="o">one</button>
<button class="t">two</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select style="display:none">
  <option value="0">zero</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
<button class=btn data-select-val="0">zero</button>
<button class=btn data-select-val="1">one</button>
<button class=btn data-select-val="2">two</button>

$('select').change(function() {  
   alert($(this).val());
});
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $("select").val($(this).data("select-val")).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.trigger` function to raise `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    alert("ok");
});

$('.z').click(function(){
    $("select").val('0').change();
});
$('.o').click(function(){
    $("select").val('1').change();;
});
$('.t').click(function(){
    $("select").val('2').change();;
});
```